# Finding all combination of a word with length 3 or more

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am trying to implement a program to find all possible combinations of a word with length 3 or more.
I have implemented algo with prints all the combinations like for example:
for word "digital" it will print
digitla
diitgla
...
and so on.
But I also need words with length 3 or more in the output.
For example: dig, dit, git, and so on.

Can anyone help me what code shall I include to get the above output?

```
public class PermTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "digital";
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer(str);
    doPerm(strBuf,str.length());

}

private static void doPerm(StringBuffer str, int index){

    if(index <= 0)
        System.out.println(str);            
    else { //recursively solve this by placing all other chars at       current first pos
        doPerm(str, index-1);
        int currPos = str.length()-index;
        for (int i = currPos+1; i < str.length(); i++) {//start swapping all other chars with current first char
            swap(str,currPos, i);
            doPerm(str, index-1);
            swap(str,i, currPos);//restore back my string buffer
        }
    } 
}

private  static void swap(StringBuffer str, int pos1, int pos2){
    char t1 = str.charAt(pos1);
    str.setCharAt(pos1, str.charAt(pos2));
    str.setCharAt(pos2, t1);
} 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666903/every-combination-of-character-array

Comment: I am able to get all the combinations. What I am trying is to get other combinations of length 3 or more

Comment: What about the following suggestion: When entering the for loop, add "if(currPos>=3) System.out.println(str.substirng(0, currPos));" - This should spit out all prefixes of found solutions with minimal length of 3

Comment: I noticed something in the program. After trying the above it is giving me the string with length 3 or above but if I enter a string with length it does not give me a string with less 3